# Having an issue with running an external programs arguments in C#

Tags: c#, arguments, argument-passing

I have the following command which works fine in Perl

```
my $bugcmd = `"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\McAfee\\VirusScan Enterprise\\scan32.exe" 
    $source /all /archive /loguser /prompt /log $path$itemID.txt /autoexit`;
```

However in C# I cannot for the life of me get the damn thing to create a log file in C# it scans it just doesn't create a log, any help would be appreciated.

```
string log = txtSource.Text + itemID + ".txt";

ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\McAfee\VirusScan Enterprise\scan32.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = drive + " /all /archive /loguser /prompt /autoexit /log" + log;
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

The path and the itemID look fine in the debugger. C:\Temp\itemID.txt

Comment: You're missing a space after `/log`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `string.Format` might help expose where the problem is (you're missing a space after `\log`). I think this might help:

```
startInfo.Arguments = 
    string.Format("{0} /all /archive /loguser /prompt /autoexit /log {1}", drive, log);
```

Sometimes it's a good idea to ensure that the log path is surrounded by quotes as well, if you're reading it from a .config or some other place that you don't have control, since it may have spaces in it. This might also apply to `drive`?

To handle that case:

```
startInfo.Arguments = 
    string.Format("\"{0}\" /all /archive /loguser /prompt /autoexit /log \"{1}\"", 
        drive, log);
```

Comment: thanks for responding, I had actually tried a space after log but it didn't work either, but perhaps I had another issue as well. I got it working today so thanks again and thanks for the other examples :-)